# How to Insert new data to JSON file with Python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have some problem about my code with python. 
I want to insert new data to json file

**file.json**

```
{
  "datas": [
    {
      "KD": "AC0001",
      "TI": "24",
      "TO": "25",
      "AR": "7.21",
      "SG": "100",
      "DT": "2019-02-12 10:44:10"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to insert new line to be like this

```
 {
      "datas": [
        {
          "KD": "AC0001",
          "TI": "24",
          "TO": "25",
          "AR": "7.21",
          "SG": "100",
          "DT": "2019-02-12 10:44:10"
        },{
          "KD": "AC0001",
          "TI": "23",
          "TO": "21",
          "AR": "7.21",
          "SG": "90",
          "DT": "2019-02-12 10:44:10"
        }
      ]
    }
```

this is my code

```
        student_data = {"data": []}
        data_holder = student_data["data"]
        counter = 0
        data_holder.append({'KD': 'AC0001','TI': '23','TO': '21','AR': '7.21,'SG': '90','DT': '2019-02-12 10:44:10'})

        with open('file.json') as f:
            data = json.load(f)

        data.update(student_data)


        file_path = 'file.json'
        with open(file_path, 'w') as outfile:
            print("writing file to: ", file_path)
            # HERE IS WHERE THE MAGIC HAPPENS
            json.dump(data, outfile, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
        outfile.close()
        print("done")
```

**and actually this is code update json file, not Insert new data**

Comment: I'm a Java person, but I don't see any Java code here -- why the Java question tag?

Comment: Why don't you just delete the first line, and load the `json` at the top of your script as `student_data = json.load(f)`?

Comment: fix syntax error in `data_holder.append(....` line. Even SO's syntax highlighting tells you it's broken...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
import json
new_data = {'KD': 'AC0001', 'TI': '23', 'TO': '21',
            'AR': '7.21', 'SG': '90', 'DT': '2019-02-12 10: 44: 10'}
file_path = 'file.json'
with open(file_path) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data['datas'].append(new_data)

    with open(file_path, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)
```